# how to get whole Date object from input date and input time in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these two inputs:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="year">
<input type="time" ng-model="time">
```

I want to create a Date object from these two values. Something like this:

```
new Date(year, time);
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @mindparse would you please tell me which one of those methods takes two parameters in the form of year and time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually add the two dates together in your controller. If you want this to automatically update on your controller scope, then you can use a watch expression in tandem with the date arithmetic. For example:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['year', 'time'], function (values) {
    var year = values[0], time = values[1];
    $scope.date = new Date(year.getYear(), year.getMonth(), year.getDay(), time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds(), time.getMilliseconds());
});
```

Then you can use `date` on your scope however you wish, and it will automatically update whenever `year` or `time` change.

---

Note that built-in support for `input[type=date]` is only available in Angular 1.3.x or later. Earlier versions will not give you access to the date in your model.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below format.

If hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds values are not known, give '0' in place of them.

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

here the variable 'd' will return the date object, from which you get epoch time also.